# Laravel Form Validation: either one of the three fields is required

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel rule for validation which is like this:-

```
 $ruleCondition  = array(
     'home_address'          => 'required_if:delivery,y',
     'office_address'        => 'required_if:delivery,y',
     'farm_house_address'    => 'required_if:delivery,y',
 );
```

If `delivery` is `y`, then `home_address`, `office_address` and `farm_house_address` are required.

However, I want to modify this a bit. If `delivery` is `y`, then either one of the `home_address`, `office_address` or `farm_house_address` would be required.

How can I do this?

Comment: only 1 of them is required but more than one could be submitted?

Comment: @lagbox yes, at least only one is required, but multiple can be submitted

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sometimes`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#validating-when-present) like this

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'delivery' => 'required', # Assumt this is your delivery
    'home_address' => 'sometimes|required',
    'office_address' => 'sometimes|required',
    'farm_house_address' => 'sometimes|required',
]);

# Custom validation

$validator->sometimes(['home_address', 'office_address', 'farm_house_address'], function ($input) {
    return !empty($input->home_address) || !empty($input->office_address) || !empty($input->farm_house_address);
}, 'required_if:delivery,y');
```

after if logic to `$validator->fails()`  handle fail

> Not sure `$input->home_address` or `$input['home_address']`. Please check

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional validators that require each without the otheres:

```
 $ruleCondition  = array(
     'home_address'          => 'required_if:delivery,y|required_without:office_address,farm_house_address',
     'office_address'        => 'required_if:delivery,y|required_without:home_address,farm_house_address',
     'farm_house_address'    => 'required_if:delivery,y|required_without:home_address,office_address',
 );
```

(note: I've not tested this but it should work)

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-required-without

Answer (score 0):

```
$rules = [
    'delivery' => 'required', // Ensure delivery is selected
];

// Custom validation logic
if (request()->input('delivery') === 'y') {
    $rules['home_address'] = 'required_without:office_address,farm_house_address';
    $rules['office_address'] = 'required_without:home_address,farm_house_address';
    $rules['farm_house_address'] = 'required_without:home_address,office_address';
}

$validator = validator()->make(request()->all(), $rules);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).